# What info to log/store about a user login?

Tags: authentication, logging

Currently I am saving LastLoginAt, LastActionAt, LastLogoutAt, and LastLoginFromIPAddress. I am not so sure about the value of logging/saving details of logouts and IP addresses, as I am not sure of what use they would actually be. What is the "best" practice here when it comes to saving info about user logins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide any specifics about your app, but you generally should log much more than you're currently storing. See [this logging Cheat Sheet for more details.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Logging_Cheat_Sheet#Which_events_to_log)

Generally: if you only store info about "last" actions, you have very little to work with if you need to use any of that data at a later date.

Even for a "simple" web app I've found it extremely useful to store a full log of login/logout actions, with associated IP addresses and even the User-Agent string (if it's a web app).
You should probably also log invalid login attempts (user_id, time, ip_address) to do some sort of rate limiting and/or password brute-forcing detection.

Simple example: if a user contacts you about his account being "hacked" (password was stolen or guessed), you need to have a full log of logins to do any meaningful analysis.

Comment: It is a web app for consumers. Should I do all this logging in a database or a file?

Comment: That's a very broad question with no clear answer. If you want you can provide much more detail and ask a question on http://stackoverflow.com/.